# JDBC optimize MySql request on Multithread

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, jdbc

I'm building a webcrawler and I'm looking for the best way to handle my requests and connection between my threads and the database (MySql).

I've 2 types of threads :

> 1. Fetchers :  They crawl websites. They produce url and add they into 2 tables : table_url and table_file. They select from table_url
>      to continue the crawl. And update table_url to set visited=1 when they
>      have read a url. Or visited=-1 when they are reading it. They can
>      delete row.
> 2. Downloaders :  They download files. They select from table_file. They update table_file to change the Downloaded column. They never
>      insert anything.

Right now I'm working with this :
I've a pool of connection based on [c3p0](http://www.javatips.net/blog/2013/12/c3p0-connection-pooling-example).
Every target (website) have thoses variables :

```
private Connection connection_downloader;
private Connection connection_fetcher;
```

I create both connection only once when I instanciate a website. Then every thread will use thoses connections based on their target.

Every thread have thoses variables :

```
private Statement statement;
private ResultSet resultSet;
```

Before every Query I open a SqlStatement :

```
public static Statement openSqlStatement(Connection connection){
    try {
        return connection.createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

And after every Query I close sql statement and resultSet with :

```
public static  void closeSqlStatement(ResultSet resultSet, Statement statement){
    if (resultSet != null) try { resultSet.close(); } catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Right now my Select queries only work with one select (I never have to select more than one for now but this will change soon) and is defined like this :

```
public static  String sqlSelect(String Query, Connection connection, Statement statement, ResultSet resultSet){
    String result = null;
    try {
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(Query);
        resultSet.next();
        result = resultSet.toString();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    closeSqlStatement(resultSet, statement);
    return result;
}
```

And Insert, Delete and Update queries use this function :

```
public static int sqlExec(String Query, Connection connection, Statement statement){
    int ResultSet = -1;
    try {
        ResultSet = statement.executeUpdate(Query);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    closeSqlStatement(resultSet, statement);
    return ResultSet;
}
```

My question is simple : can this be improved to be faster ? And I'm concerned about mutual exclusion to prevent a thread to update a link while another is doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your design is flawed. Having one connection assigned full-time for one website will severly limit your overall workload.

As you already have setup a connection pool, it's perfectly okay to **fetch before you use** (and return afterwards).

Just the same, `try-with-catch` for **closing** all your `ResultSet`s and `Statement`s after will make code more readable - and using `PreparedStatement` instead of `Statement` would not hurt as well.

One Example (using a static dataSource() call to access your pool):

```
public static String sqlSelect(String id) throws SQLException {
    try(Connection con = dataSource().getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT row FROM table WHERE key = ?")) {
          ps.setString(1, id);
          try(ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery()) {
            if(rs.next()) {
              return rs.getString(1);
            } else {
              throw new SQLException("Nothing found");
            }
          }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Following the same pattern I suggest you create methods for all the different Insert/Update/Selects your application uses as well - all using the connection only for the short time inside the DB logic.

Comment: Do you mean that it's better to always ask for a new connection than use an already existed one ? Isn't it slower ?

Comment: you use a connection pool - so that's not really a "new" but rather a "recycled" connection. So you can share a low number of connections between many, many objects

Comment: I used a connection pool thinking it would be better since I'm building a multithread application. Was I right ? And is it safe (for the data integrity ?)

Comment: yes, connection pool is fine. And regarding data integrity: think about what you need done in *onw transaction* and then put all that code in using a single connection

Comment: One more thing : I never have to close a connection ? Just the resultSet and Statement ?

Comment: oh you **absolutely have to** - the try-with-resource I provided does this already. Closing the connection in this case is merely "returning it to the pool"

Answer (score 0):

I can not see a real advantage to have all the Database stuff in your webcrawler threads.

Why don't you use a static class with the sqlSelect and sqlExec method, but without the Connection and ResultSet parameters. Both connection objects are static as well. Make sure the connection objects are valid befor using them.